# How do I perform a simple substitution encryption in python?

Tags: python, encryption

Sorry if this is a really simple question but I'm very new to python and I'm confused as to where to even start with this.

What I need to do is substitute at least 5 letters from a sentence to produce a new encrypted sentence i.e `"Hello my name is TGMezza"` could be encrypted using `('H':'1', 'e':'2', 'l':'3', 'o':'4', 'm':'5')` so it would instead read `"12334 5y n15e is TGM2zza"`. I know this is probably a really simple question but I'd appreciate as much explanation of how to do this as possible because I'm such a newbie to this and all I've been able to find on my searches are much more complicated forms of encryption like a caesar cipher.

Comment: So ist not a coding service. You are expected to show us what you have tried so far and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: I recommend you start your search with How to replace a letter or string and not directly with encryption. This will surely lead to results you can understand even as a beginner. :) https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
replacements = { 'H':'1', 'e':'2', 'l':'3', 'o':'4', 'm':'5' }
s = "Hello my name is TGMezza"
for key in replacements:
    s = s.replace(key,replacements[key])
print(s)
```

Or

```
replacements = { 'H':'1', 'e':'2', 'l':'3', 'o':'4', 'm':'5' }
s = "Hello my name is TGMezza"
s = ''.join(replacements[x] if x in replacements else x for x in s)
```

Comment: You really should add a little bit of explanatory text to your answer. FWIW, you could do this with `str.translate`, but I guess this is probably homework, and the OP is expected to do it with a loop, like your code does.

Comment: Using `reduce(lambda x,y:x+y...` to build strings is _really_ inefficient. You should use `''.join` instead.

Comment: Have made the edit.. thanks. But is there any reason why join is faster? Just curious..

Comment: Building a string in a loop with concatenation is essentially a O(n²) operation, whether you do it with a `for` loop or `reduce` (and using `reduce` like you're doing with a `lambda` involves a slow Python function call for every concatenation) . Python strings are immutable, so when you add a new substring a whole new string needs to be allocated & all the characters copied to the new string. True, that happens at C speed, and the `str` type optimises simple concatenation operations on strings (unless they're really big), but it's generally best to avoid doing that.

Comment: (cont) In contrast, `''.join` is a O(n) operation: it scans the list to determine the destination string size, allocates space for that string, then scans again to do the copying.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#str.translate) method to translate each character into another character:

```
translation = str.maketrans("Hello", "12345") # Creates the table to convert "H" to "1" etc.
# or:
tranlation = str.maketrans({'H':'1', 'e':'2', 'l':'3', 'o':'4', 'm':'5'})

text = "Hello my name is TGMezza"
print(text.translate(translation))
```